# lftp: avoid creating the directory being mirrored

Tags: http, mirroring

I am using the following to mirror a directory on my local machine:

```
  echo "set ssl:verify-certificate no" >> ~/.lftp/rc

  lftp -c mirror --verbose=3 https://x.com/nlp_data
```

This creates a `nlp_data` directory first, which I don't want. I want the files directly copied to the current directory, without creating `nlp_data`.

Ps: Any way to disable the SSL check on the command line itself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an environment handy to test this, but just from reading the documentation:

> Mirror specified source directory to local target directory. If target directory ends with a slash, the source base name is appended to target directory name. Source and/or target can be URLs pointing to directories.

I'd expect one of these variants to work:

```
lftp -c mirror --verbose=3 https://example.com/nlp_data .
lftp -c mirror --verbose=3 https://example.com/nlp_data/*
```

<sub>note that the second variant will skip hidden files and folders</sub>